# Adding/Removing Custom Kivy Widgets from .py File

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm trying to add lot of boxlayout widgets to a scrolls view and when I refresh the screen I'm trying to clear them all and add new sets of them, but what I don't understand is why it takes longer and longer every time I refresh to add same amount of widgets? Seem like clear_widget() clears the screen but it doesn't delete the reference to the class so its taking up the memory. I'm fairly new so I could be 100% percent wrong on what I'm doing but any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from datetime import datetime
from kivy.clock import Clock
import sys, os, psutil

kv = """
<hourly_banner>
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDSeparator:

    MDBoxLayout:
        size_hint: 0.95, 1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
        orientation: "horizontal"
        
        MDLabel:
            size_hint_x: 0.475
            text: root.weather_code
            font_size: self.height * 0.275
            halign: "center"

        MDBoxLayout:

            size_hint_x: 0.2
            MDIcon:
                icon: root.percip_icon
                font_size: self.height*0.375
            MDLabel:
                text: root.percip_percent
                font_size: self.height*0.275
                halign: "center"
    MDSeparator:
    
    
Screen:

    MDScrollViewRefreshLayout:
        id: refresh_layout_hourly
        refresh_callback: app.refresh_callback_hourly
        root_layout: root
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}


        MDGridLayout:
            id: hourly_grid
            cols: 1
            adaptive_height: True
            padding: "10dp", "0dp"
            row_default_height: "50dp"
            row_force_default: True
"""

class hourly_banner(MDBoxLayout):
    percip_percent = StringProperty()
    weather_code = StringProperty()
    percip_icon = StringProperty()


class Test(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def on_start(self):
        self.setup_screen()

    def setup_screen(self):

        hourly_grid = self.root.ids['hourly_grid']

        print("Before clear Memory = {0}".format(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2))
        print("Ref before clear = {0}".format(sys.getrefcount(hourly_banner)))
        self.root.ids['hourly_grid'].clear_widgets()
        print("After clear Memory = {0} ".format(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2))
        print("Ref After clear = {0}".format(sys.getrefcount(hourly_banner)))
        before = datetime.now()
        for i in range(109):
            hourly_grid.add_widget(hourly_banner(weather_code="Freezing Heavy Rain", percip_icon="water-percent",
                                   percip_percent="0"))

        print("Time to add widgets = {}".format(datetime.now() - before))
        self.root.ids.refresh_layout_hourly.refresh_done()

    def refresh_callback_hourly(self, *args):
        print("\nrefresh callback 2")

        def refresh_callback(dt):

            self.setup_screen()
            Clock.unschedule(refresh_callback)

        Clock.schedule_once(refresh_callback, 1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

Comment: I suspect you're triggering some infinite loop of repeated widget resets or something, but I'm not familiar with MDScrollViewRefreshLayout or whether it could be making that possible. Are you able to reproduce the issue without using that widget? Also, adding and removing many widgets manually is never efficient, better to use a recycleview type method.

Comment: I tried adding it under ScrollView instead of MDScrollViewRefreshLayout and it did the same thing @inclement

Comment: I also tried adding 100 buttons instead of the MDBoxLayouts but that also had the same behavior

Comment: Can you post a minimal example that doesn't use kivymd, then?